# How do I write a shell script that repeats a java program a specific number of times?

Tags: bash, shell

Essentially I am looking to write a shell script, likely using a for loop, that would allow me to repeat a program call multiple times without having to do it by hand (I don't know exactly how to explain this, but i want to perform the java TestFile.java command in the cmd window multiple times without doing it by hand).

I am trying to write it for the UNIX shell in bash, if that helps at all.

My program outputs a set of numbers that I want to look at to analyze end behavior, so I need to perform many tests for many different inputs and I want to streamline the process. I have a pretty basic understanding of shell scripting - i tried to teach myself today but I couldn't really understand the syntax of the for loop or the syntax of how to write a .java file call, but I would be able to write them in shell script with a little help.

Comment: Always a great idea to test code and have the process of running tests automated and streamlined so that testing is easy. The bash script answers will stream in but while that is happening I would suggest that you consider using jUnit for testing instead. See http://www.junit.org/ for more info. Writing junit tests would be the ultimate in automated testing for your Java app and you can get plenty of help here writing those tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

javac Testfile.java # compile the program

for((i=1;i<=50;i++))
do
echo "Output of Iteration $i" >> outfile
java Testfile >> outfile
done
```

This will compile your java program and run it for 50 times and store the output in a file named `outfile`. Likewise, you can change the 50 for the number of iterations you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do

#insert file run command here

done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

LOOPS=50
for i IN {1 .. LOOPS} 
do
   java TestFile >> out.log
done
```